# GHC's readBin function from Numeric Library is not being recognised by GHCI

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I am trying to use the `readBin` function from the Numeric Library but `ghci` is telling me that it is not in scope. Other functions like `readOct` and `readHex` are working. What could be the problem here?

Here is the error message:

```
Prelude> import Numeric
Prelude Numeric> :t readBin

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Variable not in scope: readBin
    • Perhaps you meant ‘readLn’ (imported from Prelude)
Prelude Numeric> :t readHex
readHex :: (Eq a, Num a) => ReadS a
Prelude Numeric> readHex "deadbeef"
[(3735928559,"")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using GHC 9.0.2 or older. Those versions didn't have `readBin` yet.

(Or more accurately, `base-4.15.1.0` and older didn't have that function yet.)